# How to resize subviews within a ScrollView using Gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, uigesturerecognizer

i'd like to know how to resize subviews within a ScrollView using gestures, specifically Pinch Gestures. I don't want to scale (I mean, I don't need to Zoom in/out) its content, but I need to resize the view's frame. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add pinch gesture recognizer to your mainView:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinchGesture:)];
pinchGesture.delegate = self;
[mainView addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];
[pinchGesture release];
```

then react to the pinch:

```
- (IBAction)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            if([sender scale] < 1){
                NSArray *subViews = [mainView subviews];
                for( UIView *view in subViews){
                     //Adjust the size of your subview however you like
                     CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(x,x,x,x);
                     view.frame = newFrame;
                }
            }else if([sender scale] > 1){ 
                //resize frame (zoom in)

            } 

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If your mainView has an option `@property(nonatomic) BOOL autoresizesSubviews` set to `YES` you could just resize the mainView frame otherwise you will have to go through all the mainView subviews and resize them accordingly

Comment: Actually, what I need is to resize just the subviews, not the mainView. And also, i don't want to zoom anything, just resize. But I just don't know how to resize using gestures.

Comment: I provided you with a general way to react to a pinch gesture and to know the scale of the pinch. What you will do with it is your choice. You can easily just manipulate the subviews frames.

Comment: Can you give a little example on how to do that plz? I'm a noob in gesture and animations. Sry for that.

Comment: Just edited the code a bit. You can do what ever you like withe the subviews, but it all depends on your subview structures and such...

Comment: Just a little last question. When I'm making the new frame, I would like it to be proportional to the pinch gesture, similar to when you do the scaling. How should I pass the parameters in the CGRectMake in order to acomplish that? Btw, I'm giving you the check for this answer, but I would like to know that last part plz =/

Comment: the `[sender scale]` property which is a scale factor relative to the points of the two touches in screen coordinates. This property will be different for each direction. You can use that property to multiply the frames parameters.