# How to make UIScrollView actual resize its child views when zoom in/out

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

When `UIScrollview` uses pinch gesture to zoom in then it transform it content view. The actual size of the child views remains same. I want to change the frame of all "subviews" as `UIScroll` zoom on pinch gesture.

Comment: use this may be help full.. 

[How to resize subviews within a ScrollView using Gestures][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681326/how-to-resize-subviews-within-a-scrollview-using-gestures

Comment: i have already try that concept. but pinch gesture's recognizer scale continuously changing thats why the resizing of view happens very fast and it is lagging and looking weird.